# mysql fetch error

Tags: php

```
    <? 
    $res = $database->userLatestStatus($u);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
       $status=$row['status'];
       echo "$status";
    }
    ?>
```

This is the code on my page, which is throwing up the following error:
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource....

The database function:

```
   function userLatestStatus($u)
   {
       $q = "SELECT status FROM ".TBL_STATUS." WHERE userid = '$u' DESC LIMIT 1";
       return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: FIXED, SORRY FOR THE POST. MISSED ORDER BY!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1):

Use a query like `ORDER BY UPDATETIME DESC` or remove `DESC`

Answer (score 0):

`DESC` should be used with [`ORDER BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

Comment: Please don't link to W3Schools.